# How to make an object visible in other classes in different screens?

Tags: class, object, flutter, screen

I'm doing a project using Flutter and I need to make an object visible in other classes (these classes are in different screens). I'll give an example to be more clear.
Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Person{

 String name;
 String job;
 String city;

}
```

I have 3 different screens, in each screen I'll read one atribute, so I need to read the name of the person in the screen 1, his job in the screen 2 and his city in the screen 3 using the same object, It's probably a stupid question, but my knowledge in programming isn't very deep

I hope I was clear enough, sorry if there is any mistakes on my english

Answer (score 0):

You coud use a singleton with the get_it package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

class Person {
  Person();

  String name;
  String job;
  String city; 
}

GetIt getIt = GetIt();
final personModel = getIt.get<Person>();

void main() { 
  getIt.registerSingleton<Person>(Person());
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
        body: MyHomePage()
      ),
      routes: {
        'home': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        'page1': (context) => Page1(),
      }
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 TextEditingController namectrl = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController jobctrl = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController cityctrl = TextEditingController();

  save() {
    personModel.name = namectrl.text.toString();
    personModel.job = jobctrl.text.toString();
    personModel.city = cityctrl.text.toString(); 
    Navigator.pushNamed(context,'page1');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                 children: <Widget>[
                       Text(
                        'Name'
                      ),

                      TextField(
                          controller: namectrl,
                      ),
                       Text(
                        'job'
                      ),

                      TextField(
                          controller: jobctrl,
                      ),

                       Text(
                        'city'
                      ),

                      TextField(
                          controller: cityctrl,
                      ),


                   IconButton(
                     icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                     onPressed: () {save();}
                     )
                 ],
                 ),
             )
           ),
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

Future<bool> controlBackButton() async {
  return false;
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
              child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text('City: ' + personModel.city),
            title: Text('Name: ' + personModel.name),
            subtitle: Text('Job: ' + personModel.job),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You might find that Shared Preferences have their own limitations and BLOC, InheritedWidget etc are too complicated.

Comment: The Provider wrapper for InheritedWidget makes it much simpler.

Comment: Please post your answer so that the OP can chose what is simpler for him. I'm developing a non-trivial application with this method and find it much simpler once you have several widgets across several pages.